# Like visible on menu

Tags: jquery, css, facebook, iframe

I have facebook like button on website and drop down menu.

The problem is that button is visible when menu is used.

I know that I can add atrribute (html)

```
<iframe allowTransparent="true" ...
```

and this should work,
but is there a way to do this in other method maybe with jquery or css trick.

Button is build with iframe so it is probably problem with making iframe transparent.

Comment: should  be able to do it with either but it is hard to tell without seeing the code for the menu.

Comment: It is mega drop down menu by design chemical demo is here http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu-plugin/examples/

Comment: have you tried changing the z-index of the menu dropdown? something high, like 2000

Comment: Seems to work. Strange I try earlier but maybe I've added for wrong element. Thanks

Comment: Strange I have now problem with youtube iframe I try with jquery  $('iframe.youtube-player').each(function(){
            var url = $(this).attr("src");
            $(this).attr("src",url+"?wmode=transparent"); add transparent but it is not working.
           });

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to dynamically hide/show the Facebook button when the menu is used. You could add an event listener for `mouseover` and `mouseout` that would set the `<iframe>` to `display = 'none'`.